# How do I correctly use of the spread operator in Flutter / Dart as opposed to JavaScript?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a wrapper around HttpClient.post() where I want to add a user's location to every post request he does. I tried using the spread operator for this in the same way I would do in JavaScript but Dart won't let me.

```
Future post(String route, dynamic body) async {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  http.Response response = await client.post(Uri.parse(baseUrl + route),
      body: {...body, position.toJson()},
      headers: {'x-access-token': await authController.readJwt()});
  return response;
}
```

It worked fine when I was just passing `body: body` but now I get

`flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

`print(position)` looks like `Latitude: 37.785834, Longitude: -122.406417`

Answer (score 2):

Your body looks like this right now:

```
{
   "key1" : "value1", //From spread operator
   "key2" : "value2", //From spread operator
   "key3" : "value3", //From spread operator
   {
      "lat" : "something1",
      "lng" : "something2",
   }

}
```

Assigning a key yo your .toJson object should solve the problem:

```
  body: {...body, "position" : position.toJson()},
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked using
body: {...body, "position": jsonEncode(position.toJson())}